# Switching the front and back histograms in a grouped plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, histogram

I'm making a figure with two histograms overlaid on the same plot (grouped by time) and I want the time 0hr histogram to be in front of the time 24hr histogram so it is easier to see. I tried switching the order of the dataframe (i.e. time 0 values in first rows and time 24 values after) but that did not change anything.

This is my code and the resultant plot:

```
pHs <- ggplot(pH_yes, aes(x=pH,fill=time_hr,color=time_hr)) 
pHs <- pHs +  geom_histogram(bins=70,alpha=0.6,position ="identity")
pHs <- pHs + theme_bw()
pHs <- pHs + ggtitle(title2) + xlab("pH") + ylab("count")
pHs <- pHs + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,16,by=2),limits = c(0,16))
pHs <- pHs + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(3,7,by=0.2),limits = c(4.6,5.8))
pHs <- pHs + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12,hjust = 0.5))
pHs <- pHs + scale_fill_manual(values = c("pink1","aquamarine"))
pHs <- pHs + scale_color_manual(values = c("violet","skyblue"))
pHs
```

figure with the not-desired histogram order: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXz3y.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the factor levels of the fill/color variable (along with switching the order of colors in the fill/color scales)

```r
ggplot(pH_yes, aes(x = pH, fill = forcats::fct_rev(time_hr),
                   color = forcats::fct_rev(time_hr))) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 70, alpha = 0.6, position = "identity", na.rm = TRUE) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = title2, x = "pH", y = "count") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 16, by = 2),limits = c(0,16)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(3, 7, by = 0.2),limits = c(4.6,5.8)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("aquamarine", "pink1"), name = "time") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("skyblue", "violet"), name = "time")
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)

pH_yes <- data.frame(pH = c(rnorm(200, 5, 0.5), rnorm(400, 5.5, 0.5)),
                     time_hr = rep(c("0 hr", "24 hr"), times = c(200, 400)))

title2 <- "BSAFE pH in 0.5% lactose"
```